# Compiling C++ using VisualStudioCode on OSX

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, c++

Total novice C++ user going thru tutorials using Visual Studio Code on OSX.
Barest bones Hello World program

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Then I run-compile in VSCodes terminal using

```
$ g++ Foo.cpp -o foo
```

My question is, shouldn't I be seeing the Hello, World! out put in the terminal? Or will this only be visible if I compile and run in Windows?

Comment: Have you only compiled the program, or did you also run it and got nothing?

Comment: Yes compiled and I see an executable but nothing in the VS terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have compiled the program and need to run it.

The simplest way is to use in VScode the key-combination
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>
to compile (if required) and run.
If any errors are found, the compiler will display them; otherwise
"Hello, World!" will be printed out.
There are also menu equivalents for this shortcut.

On the Mac you should replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> by <kbd>Cmd</kbd>.